# Duplicate rows being added to datagrid when adding in for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagrid

When I output the generated value into in the datagrid it puts the same value about 15 times before adding a unique value into the the datagrid. Does anyone know any solutions or workarounds to this problem? Also note that I am running this for loop within another for loop to generate a specific amount of values.

```
   var parts = new List<string>();
            string hash = CalculateMD5Hash(identifier);
            for (var i = 0; i < 32; i += 2)
            {
                string chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRTUVWXY";
                var nextDigit = Convert.ToInt32(hash.Substring(i, 2), 16) & 31;
                var withDash = (((i % 8) == 0) && (i > 0));


                parts.Add(withDash ? "-" : "");
                parts.Add(chars.Substring(nextDigit, 1));




            }
            string[] array = parts.ToArray();
            string joined = string.Join("", array);

            string output = identifier + ":" + joined;
            string[] keySplit = output.Split(':');

            outputGrid.Rows.Add(keySplit[0], keySplit[1]); //Outputs mulitple times
```

Comment: We need to see both loops to identify your problem

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you're trying to obtain? The description is not really clear which may explain the downvote. Can you share more code like @DanielLoudon said?

Comment: @Daniel Loudan @Mikitori for the other loop since im allowing user input im just doing ` for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) { //code in the post } exaple of output: https://i.imgur.com/hily9ej.png

Comment: That hash is getting the same number.  Use the debugger to confirm. There is nothing Random about part of the string version of a MD5 hash, so there isnt much reason to expect them to be different

Comment: @Plutonix i can confirm its different because each time i am converting to md5 its a unique value

Comment: @Plutonix when i check the value im converting to md5 i check usinga messagebox and it seems to be proper when its slowed down

Comment: It's probably because the identifier doesn't change and it's printing the identifier multiple times

Comment: @Daniel Loudon the identifier is changing i double checked. i used messageboxes to confirm. but when it slows down it outputs correct. im thinking its outputting to the datagrid before the program has time to calculate the md5 hash and do the bitwise operations

Comment: That wouldn't be the case, please update your question with the code that changes the identifier because from what you have posted the identifier doesn't change

Comment: @Daniel Loudon since i dont know how to update the post. heres the code that is generating the identifier https://pastebin.com/9ng1f5rP

Comment: So inside the outer most loop you have "identifier= genId();", this is different from what you said in an earlier comment. You should post a complete example with all your code including this loop and the outermost loop so we can understand why this is happening.

Comment: From what I see the GenId() returns a string of length 5 which is coincidentally the same length of the value that is repeating 15 times.  We need to see how the value of 'amount' is being set in outer most loop to see the problem

Comment: @DanielLoudon ive updated the code on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/3YCRAJms but i removed the amount value because that was left from previous attempts to solve this problem but in the datagrid im also outputting the the ID just for testing purposes https://i.imgur.com/npDGoaM.png

Comment: Your calling GenKey(string identifier) but passing in two values? This is confusing me because your GenKey() takes one parameter..

Comment: @DanielLoudon sorry my bad i forgot to remove that part

Comment: What's the value of numOfKeys and how many rows are being printed to the data grid view?

Comment: @DanielLoudon numOfKeys is just the textbox text converted to an integer using Convert.ToInt32 which is obviously the number of keys and whatever the value is in the textbox the number of rows it is with the data inside

Comment: I'll post my next comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of generating multiple random classes, it's best to practice to use one random class as there is a chance that random classes can have the same seed and generate the same numbers. This is because it relies on the clock to create the seed and in a loop where there may not be a lot of time between each initialisation, multiple classes will have the same random seed value and produce the same set of "random" numbers hence the same ID generated multiple times . Initialise one random class will eliminate this risk.

```
private static readonly Random generator = new Random(); 
private static readonly object syncLock = new object(); 
public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    lock(syncLock) {
        return generator.Next(min, max); 
       }
 }
```

And in your `GenId()` method:

```
string digiList = "0123456789";
string alphaList = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY";

  string id = digiList[randomNumber(0, digiList.Length)].ToString();
   id += alphaList[randomNumber(0, alphaList.Length)].ToString();
   id += alphaList[randomNumber(0, alphaList.Length)].ToString();
   id += digiList[randomNumber(0, digiList.Length)].ToString();
   id += digiList[randomNumber(0, digiList.Length)].ToString();

   return id;
```

Comment: alright im going to try it ill report back if it works

Comment: Your random class is initialised based on the clock, so having the random class initialised inside the loop may result in multiple classes have the same seed and produces the same values. Worth a shot because I've nothing else lol

Comment: That's why we need more code than you think! You can update your question by clicking the 'Edit' button beneath your post btw. You're welcome :)

Comment: thanks again and yeah we definitely do need more code than we think :D